# Save to desktop without the exact path

Tags: java

I want to save a file in my desktop. So I have

```
FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\path_to_Dekstop\\print.xls"));
```

and it works. But I want to save the file without put the exact path to the desktop. I searched it and I found similar questions and I came up with this solution:

```
File desktopDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
System.out.println(desktopDir.getPath() + " " + desktopDir.exists());
String pathToDesktop = desktopDir.getPath();
FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToDesktop));
```

but I got an error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\nat\Desktop (Access is denied)
```

Comment: `new File("pathToDesktop"))` ...?  You're quoting the variable...I think it should be `new File(pathToDesktop))` ...

Comment: thx for noticing. I made a mistake as I was written the question.. I have it without the quotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathToDesktop` represents the directory of the `Desktop`, you should supply a file name to write to

`FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File(desktopDir, "File to be written to"));`

Which will place the `"File to be written to"` on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can't write directly to `Desktop` as its a folder but not a `file`. You need to write to a `file`. DO something like thi s:-

```
File desktopDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
 System.out.println(desktopDir.getPath() + " " + desktopDir.exists());
 String pathToDesktop = desktopDir.getPath();
 FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToDesktop+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"print.xls"));
```

This will write to `print.xls` in `Desktop`.